# Wix Burn Bundle - Must be Administrator

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I've created a WIX Burn Bundle. In the Bundle I install .Net 4 (if its not installed) then 2 more .msi files. 1 is a third part msi the other a msi I created for my software using WIX. I need to be an Administrator on the machine to run these the .msi files.

I want the Burn bundle to not do anything if the user is not an administartor i.e. install nothing. In my product software I can easily do do using below - however I cant do this in the bundle. I've read lots of similar posts but just didnt find a working example for what I want to do.

```
<CustomAction Id="IsPrivileged" Error="You must be an Administrator to install [ProductName]." />
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='IsPrivileged' Before='LaunchConditions'>
        Not Privileged
     </Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: look for elevated permissions

Comment: One method would be to ask for admin credentials when you launch the bundle, i.e. set the execution level for it to "Require Administrator". However I see that Rob says Burn was not designed to run elevated, so you might encounter limitations: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Wix-BURN-wpf-and-UAC-promt-td7587811.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the bundle equivalent of launch conditions using [Burn's built-in variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html) and [WixBalExtension's Condition element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/condition.html):

```
<bal:Condition Message="You can't elevate.">
  <![CDATA[Privileged <> 0]]>
</bal:Condition>

<bal:Condition Message="You're not elevated.">
  WixBundleElevated = 1
</bal:Condition>
```

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why this would take no effect for me?  Runing v3.11.0.1701

Comment: The "You can't elevate." condition is not working for me in 3.11.1. Was expecting to see this message when running as user without admin privileges, but install continues as normal after system asks admin enabled user for privileges. Also not sure why 'Privileged' condition has to be escaped.