# WiX Bundle needs THE Admin vs user with admin privileges

Tags: wix, bundle

I'm developing a Wix (v3.7) Bundle installer that installs prerequisites for our software. One of the prerequisites must be installed as the default admin account on the machine - a user with elevated privileges will not work. This allows that program to run as a service that will auto-start for all users.

I've found how to force the user to "Run as administrator" in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370363/4742964.

Now I'd like to force the default/local administrator to execute the bundle. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: "default admin"?

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen "default admin" means the main administrator account on the machine. A user with administrator privileges (who right-clicks and selects "Run as Administrator") will not work. Here's a link that tells how to enable the account: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/